# Cognito Login - iOS and Server API authentication

Tags: ios, authentication, server, amazon-cognito

Before spending too much time on this I am trying to confirm if what I am trying to do will work. I have Web App and API that uses Cognito for authentication. I have an iOS app that needs to auth users which currently goes directly to Cognito. I am able to login etc. Now would this token/session if sent to the server work in allowing server to get to all the needed resources? 
I feel like we went the wrong direction and what is required is API that authenticates iOS client and iOS client should not know anything about Cognito.

Comment: You are the right direction. I have an IOS app that calls my custom API to authenitcate users , stores the session id sent back by the server in Keychainwrapper and every time I need anything from the server, I send the session id as the parameter and get  the results. Let me know if you need any kind of details or help

Comment: What I question is ability of my server to reuse the token to get to AWS resources (DB, files etc.). To me it seems that it is a problem if I authenticate iOS app, then pass that token to my server and it in turns deals with AWS services? Perhaps I am overthinking it and passing a valid token regardless of where it is coming from as long as it is valid is ok?

Comment: It should not be a problem as long as the aws service is aware of the token. The creation of the token should be at aws and then it can be passed along whatever path u want to the destination aws

Comment: yes that seems to be working, I guess I was wrong and authorization is per user regardless of device and can be passed around.